# Plotting with satisfying simultaneous condition and combining them

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a code which reproduces some mathematical calculation. And it goes like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
HeadingForTable = {"x",
   "R1", "R1A1", "R1A2", "R1A3", "R1A4",
   "R2", "R2A1", "R2A2", "R2A3", "R2A4",
   "R3", "R3A1", "R3A2", "R3A3", "R3A4"};
R2A1 = {-1, -2, -3, -4, -50, -60, -70, -80, -90, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, \
-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3};
R2A3 = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 
   0.011, 0.012, 0.013, 0.014, 0.015, 0.016, 0.017, 0.018, 0.019, 
   0.02};
TableFormat = 
  Table[{i, 
    1100 + (i - 1)*50, -135 - (i - 
        1)*10, (-135 - (i - 1)*10)*-10*0.25, -0.00056 - (i - 
        1)*0.00001, (-0.00056 - (i - 1)*0.00001)*-10*0.5, 
    2100 + (i - 1)*50, R2A1[[i]], R2A1[[i]]*10*56, R2A3[[i]], 
    R2A3[[i]]/100, 3300 + (i - 1)*50, 
    0.001 + (i)*0.001, -1*(0.001 + (i)*0.001), 10*i, -10*i}, {i, 1, 
    20}];
RowLength = Length[TableFormat];
TableForm[Join[{HeadingForTable}, TableFormat]]
```

This table consists of 20 rows and 16 columns.  Now, I first need to plot a graph with 1st column as x axis and 2nd, 7th and 12th column in y-axis, which can be accomplished by:

```
xaxis = Table[TableFormat[[i, 1]], {i, 1, RowLength}];
YAxis1 = Table[TableFormat[[i, 2]], {i, 1, RowLength}];
YAxis2 = Table[TableFormat[[i, 7]], {i, 1, RowLength}];
YAxis3 = Table[TableFormat[[i, 12]], {i, 1, RowLength}];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xaxis, #}] & /@ {YAxis1, YAxis2, YAxis3}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, ImageSize -> Large]
```

giving the plot:

[image]

I then want to plot the same with certain conditions imposed:

for the 2nd (7th and 12th ) column, I want to plot only when the absolute value of 3rd (8th and 13th) and 4th (9th and 14th ) column becomes greater than 10 and absolute value of 5th (10th and 15th) and 6th (11th and 16th) column less than 0.01.

```
UpperCutoff = 10;
LowerCutoff = 0.01;

TableFor1stRoot = Select[TableFormat,
   Abs[#[[3]]] > UpperCutoff && Abs[# [[4]]] > UpperCutoff && 
     Abs[# [[5]]] < LowerCutoff && Abs[# [[6]]] < LowerCutoff &];
TableFor2ndRoot = Select[TableFormat,
   Abs[#[[8]]] > UpperCutoff && Abs[# [[9]]] > UpperCutoff && 
     Abs[# [[10]]] < LowerCutoff && Abs[# [[11]]] < LowerCutoff &];
TableFor3rdRoot = Select[TableFormat,
   Abs[#[[13]]] > UpperCutoff && Abs[# [[14]]] > UpperCutoff && 
     Abs[# [[15]]] < LowerCutoff && Abs[# [[16]]] < LowerCutoff &];

SiftedTable1stRoot = TableFor1stRoot[[All, {1, 2}]] ;
SiftedTable2ndRoot = TableFor2ndRoot[[All, {1, 7}]] ;
SiftedTable3rdRoot = TableFor3rdRoot[[All, {1, 12}]] ;

RowLength1stRoot = Length[SiftedTable1stRoot];
RowLength2ndRoot = Length[SiftedTable2ndRoot];
RowLength3rdRoot = Length[SiftedTable3rdRoot];

xaxis1stRoot = 
  Table[SiftedTable1stRoot [[i, 1]], {i, 1, RowLength1stRoot}];
yaxis1stRoot = 
  Table[SiftedTable1stRoot [[i, 2]], {i, 1, RowLength1stRoot}];
xaxis2ndRoot = 
  Table[SiftedTable2ndRoot [[i, 1]], {i, 1, RowLength2ndRoot}];
yaxis2ndRoot = 
  Table[SiftedTable2ndRoot [[i, 2]], {i, 1, RowLength2ndRoot}];
xaxis3rdRoot = 
  Table[SiftedTable3rdRoot [[i, 1]], {i, 1, RowLength3rdRoot}];
yaxis3rdRoot = 
  Table[SiftedTable3rdRoot [[i, 2]], {i, 1, RowLength3rdRoot}];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xaxis1stRoot, #}] & /@ {yaxis1stRoot}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], 
 LabelStyle -> {16, GrayLevel[0]}]
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xaxis2ndRoot, #}] & /@ {yaxis2ndRoot}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], 
 LabelStyle -> {16, GrayLevel[0]}]
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{xaxis3rdRoot, #}] & /@ {yaxis3rdRoot}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], 
 LabelStyle -> {16, GrayLevel[0]}]
```

This gives the plot:

[image]

Since, for the 12th column, these conditions will not get satisfied (and for the same reason I cannot give all these conditions simultaneously), we will get empty plot.
I could do these by checking the conditions individually (as shown in the above code), but is there any way of doing it any simpler and combining the plots together? I am expecting a plot somewhat like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

HeadingForTable = {"x", "R1", "R1A1", "R1A2", "R1A3", "R1A4", "R2", "R2A1", 
   "R2A2", "R2A3", "R2A4", "R3", "R3A1", "R3A2", "R3A3", "R3A4"};
R2A1 = {-1, -2, -3, -4, -50, -60, -70, -80, -90, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 
   0, 1, 2, 3};
R2A3 = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 0.01, 0.011, 0.012,
    0.013, 0.014, 0.015, 0.016, 0.017, 0.018, 0.019, 0.02};
TableFormat = 
  Table[{i, 
    1100 + (i - 1)*50, -135 - (i - 
        1)*10, (-135 - (i - 1)*10)*-10*0.25, -0.00056 - (i - 
        1)*0.00001, (-0.00056 - (i - 1)*0.00001)*-10*0.5, 2100 + (i - 1)*50, 
    R2A1[[i]], R2A1[[i]]*10*56, R2A3[[i]], R2A3[[i]]/100, 3300 + (i - 1)*50, 
    0.001 + (i)*0.001, -1*(0.001 + (i)*0.001), 10*i, -10*i}, {i, 1, 20}];
RowLength = Length[TableFormat];
TableForm[Join[{HeadingForTable}, TableFormat]];
```

Use [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) to extract columns from a matrix

```
ListLinePlot[TableFormat[[All, {1, #}]] & /@ {2, 7, 12}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
sel[n_] := 
 Pick[TableFormat[[All, {1, n}]], 
  Thread[(And @@ Thread[Greater[Abs[#], 10]] & /@ 
      TableFormat[[All, {n + 1, n + 2}]]) && (And @@ 
        Thread[Less[Abs[#], 0.01]] & /@ TableFormat[[All, {n + 3, n + 4}]])]]

ListLinePlot[(sel /@ {2, 7, 12}) /. {} :> Nothing,
 PlotRange -> {800, 2800}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Combining,

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[
  Callout[
     TableFormat[[All, {1, #}]],
     HeadingForTable[[#]]] & /@ {2, 7, 12},
  PlotStyle -> Dotted,
  PlotRange -> Full,
  ImageSize -> Medium],
 ListLinePlot[
  (sel /@ {2, 7, 12}) /. {} :> Nothing,
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
  ImageSize -> Medium]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But could you please tell me what `{} :> Nothing` does and also what would be arguments of `sel[n_]`? Is it 2,7,12 ?

Comment: See documentation for  [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) `sel /@ {2, 7, 12}` maps `sel` onto the arguments `{2, 7, 12}` Since `sel[12]` evaluates to an empty list `{}` and this would interfere with plotting, `{} :> Nothing` removes the empty list. See documentation for [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) When there is a symbol or operator that you don't understand, highlight it in Mathematica and press `F1` for help.